# How do I add values of multiple text box in windows forms. C#, Visual Studios

Tags: c#, visual-studio, windows-forms-designer

I am trying to make a basic math machine with windows forms using C#.

So I have it setup with 2 text boxes, 1 label and a button.  The user puts the two values in the text boxes then they press the button to get sum of the two text boxes in the label.

I am fairly new to Windows Forms and do not know how to get the values of the text boxes and then change the Label.

Thank you.

Comment: You most probably need a Windows Forms tutorial. Hope it serves as a good start: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Is1EHXFhEe4

Comment: Okay I will check it out, Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

This is a pretty simple requirement.

Assuming integer values are entered into textboxes.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Declare variables for addition
    int a, b;
    // If convertion of textbox values to integer is successful
    // If integer parsing is successful, the value entered in textbox1 will go to variable a
    // and the value entered in textboxb will go to variable b
    if (int.TryParse(textBox1.Text, out a) && int.TryParse(textBox2.Text, out b))
    {
         // Add a and b and assign display its value in label
         label1.Text = (a + b).ToString();
    }
 }
```

Hope this helps. As the comment from Sina. I would also recommend you to go through a basic end to end C# tutorial and it would give you a quick start.

Comment: Yes this did help thank you, I also watched the video and that helped a lot too. I was confused on how to use ToString(); and parse.

Comment: Nice to know it helped you. Could you please upvote the answer if you feel its worth.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are performing mathematical operations, it would be better to implement integer validations in the textboxes. This can be done generally with the TextChange event.

As for your question, You can simple create a simple prop similar to the following to obtain textbox values:

```
public int Value1
{
    get
    {
        int value = 0;
        int.TryParse(textBox1.Text.Trim(), out value);
        return value;
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int firstnum;
    int secondnum;
    int ans;
    firstnum=int.parse(textbox1.text);
    secondnum=int.parse(textbox2.text);
    ans=firstnum+secondnum;
    label1.text=ans.Tostring();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can write a method/class like;

```
public string Add(string v1,string v2)
{
    int i1 = Convert.ToInt32(v1);
    int i2 = Convert.ToInt32(v2);

    return (i1 + i2).ToString();
}
label1.text=Add(textBox1.Text,textBox2.Text); // write into button click event
```

Answer (score 0):

```
decimal v1 = 0;
decimal v2 = 0;
decimal v3 = 0;

if (decimal.TryParse(TxtBx1.Text, out v1) & decimal.TryParse(TxtBx2.Text, out v2) & 
decimal.TryParse(Text3, out v3))
{
    decimal total = v1+v2+v
    TotalTxtBx.Text = total.ToString();
}
```